# Sinônimo de Putativo

Tags: palavra-para-ideia, sinônimos

Estou procurando um sinônimo lexicamente melhor para **putativo**.

Em minhas pesquisas vi que **putativo** seria algo que parece que é, mas não é. Algo que se leva a crer ser real após uma situação dizer que não, como alguém que age feito dono de um estabelecimento, mas na verdade é um mero funcionário<sup>[[1]](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/putativo/)</sup>.

Resolvi perguntar por aqui porque encontrei como possível sinônimo **renomado**, que até ficaria elegante no contexto para o qual irei utilizar (*<<nome do objeto>> da/de/do "putativo"*), mas em meu modesto conhecimento, não vejo essa palavra como significado real de **putativo** pois, pelas definições das palavras, me levam a crer terem cunhos diferentes, um negativo e a outro positivo.

Comment: Bruno, podes dar um exemplo? Uma frase em português (com o putativo) que queiras re-escrever de modo mais claro, ou uma numa língua estrangeira que queiras traduzir?

Comment: O suposta dono do restaurante. Putativo é suposto ou aparente.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, creio que esta correto, ambas tem diferentes objetivos, primeiro sobre os termos que citou como sendo sinônimos, então só para deixar mais claro *«putativo»* seria aquele que tem uma **falsa atribuição**, ou seja que é reputado (tem reputação) ser o que não é.

Inclusive existem dois termos que usam a palavra, um se chama «crime putativo» (ou "delito putativo") e o outro «casamento putativo»

O crime ou delito putativo é algo que só existe na representação subjetiva do agente (só na cabeça do agente). Ele quer cometer um determinado delito, há intenção nesse sentido (desvalor da intenção), mas tudo não passa dessa mera intenção (porque na realidade não há sequer fato típico ou punível).

O casamento putativo é o casamento celebrado indevidamente de boa-fé, ou seja, um *"casamento imaginário"*, no qual, se imaginava ser verdadeiro, por ter preenchido todos os requisitos de existência, validade e produzido seus efeitos, no entanto, posteriormente, verificou se um vício, suscetível à anulação.

Então creio que vai depender da frase que deseja escrever, talvez para cada um soe melhor, as vezes até duas palavras poderão soar melhor, dependendo muito mesmo da frase, então creio que poderia usar palavras nos *passado*, como:

- *Pensava* que ele era o dono.
- *Pensei* que estava na faixa correta da rodovia.
- *Pensamos* que era um homem de palavra.
- *Imaginei* que teríamos mais convidados.
- *Acreditei* que era uma animal maior que isto.

Ainda pode experimentar, dependendo da frase as seguintes palavras:

- `alegórico`, `cerebrino`, `espectral`, `fabular`, `fantasioso`, `fantasmal`, `fantástico`, `ficcional`, `fictício`, `figurado`, `hipotético`, `ilusório`, `imaginário`, `imaginoso`, `inexistente`, `infundado`, `inventado`, `irreal`, `lendário`, `mítico`, `quimérico`, `suposto`, `umbrático`, `umbrátil`, `utópico`.

Comment: É complicado explicar... Não é bem uma frase, é o nome de um objeto, parte em inglês e parte noutro idioma (justamente o "putativo"). É como se fosse *<nome do objeto> da/de/do putativo*

Comment: @BrunoAugusto teria como fornecer um exemplo? Tem que ser uma tradução literal? Não poderia adaptar o texto para o português, para soar/interpretar melhor?

Comment: Pior é que não mesmo. Esse *<<nome do objeto>> da/de/do putativo* foi a melhor reordenação de palavras que consegui formar até mesmo pra buscar referências bibliográficas para o assunto. Imagina, por exemplo, algo como *carro do putativo*, *bola do putativo*... substantivo + preposição + putativo

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Mas qual o sentido de putativo na frase? Seria algo como: *Este é o carro do suposto meliante?* ou seria o carro o *putativo*?

Comment: Vish... Não encontrei quase nada sobre o assunto, é quase como se o tema tivesse sido varrido da Internet, mas do pouco que encontrei, a melhor dedução a que pude chegar — e arriscando uma mal colocamento gramatical, foi de que o "putativo" seria "um alguém", desconhecido ou morto há muito tempo, que um dia foi dono do objeto. Carro do Suposto, bola do Suposto, por exemplo, soam bastante estranhos, por isso eu estou já há um tempo procurando um sinônimo de fácil compreensão.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto meio dificil e confuso o que esta dizendo, não consigo encontrar muito bem o sentido do que esta tentando passar, vamos supor que foi encontrado uma moeda antiga e que inicialmente acreditavam pertencer ao tesouro do barba negra (Edward Teach). Então vamos dizer que o putativo é o barba-negra, ficando assim "Esta era a moeda do putativo barba negra"? Se não foi esse o sentido eu não consigo nem ter ideia do que vc procura, se puder formular um exemplo da frase em inglês mesmo eu ficaria grato.

Comment: Geez! Finalmente descobri o que raios o objeto da foto é. É uma espada! Não parece uma, mas enfim, contextualizando ficaria "Espada do Putativo"